# Why am I getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException when creating a Client Socket in a HandlerThread?

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am updating an app that runs in Android 6.0 to Android 7.1.  The app communicates via TCP, and the original code creates a new thread in which it creates a client socket.  When I try to run it in Android 7.1, I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException.  I thought this was odd, as I thought the TCP communication was happening on a new thread, and I do not get the Exception in Android 6.0.  Snippets from the code are below.

```
// in MainActivity.java
public void ConnectToTCP() {
        m_objThreadClient = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.20.2", 5003);
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        String message; // message from TCP

                    // ...some code omitted for brevity...

                        clientSocket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
         }
         m_objThreadClient.start();
}
```

I tried moving the TCP communication to a HandlerThread, which many solutions online suggested.  I wanted to avoid AsyncTask, as I saw warnings about using it to handle tasks longer than a few seconds.  However, when I run the app with the HandlerThread, I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException in both Android 6.0 and Android 7.1.  The exception is thrown in the line that creates the Client Socket.  I used TCPThread.isAlive() to check that the thread exists, and it does.

```
// in TCPThread.java
public class TCPThread<T> extends HandlerThread {
    private static final String TAG = "TCPThread";
    private boolean mHasQuit = false;

    public TCPThread() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean quit() {
        mHasQuit = true;
        return super.quit();
    }

    public void connectToTCP() {
        // I change some button appearances and UI things on the main thread, so I created a Handler for it
        Handler mainUiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        try {
            // the next line is where the NetworkOnMainException gets thrown
            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.20.2", 5003);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String message; // message from TCP

            // ...some code omitted for brevity...

            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// in MainActivity.java
public void ConnectToTCP() {
    TCPThread<String> mTCPThread = new TCPThread<>();
    // this is a method defined in a different activity
    String currentStatus = activityConnect.currentConnectStatus();
    if (currentStatus.equals("Connected")) { // if connected and wanting to disconnect
        mTCPThread.quitSafely();
    } else {
        mTCPThread.start();
        mTCPThread.getLooper();
        mTCPThread.connectToTCP();
}
```

Comment: could you highlight which line is causing the network on main thread exception ?

Comment: Indeed you call mTCPThread.connectToTcp() on the main thread so it is executed on the main thread. You should place that internet code in the run() of your handler thread. But you are not using its run().

Comment: Your original code snippet seems fine. You might consider posting a stack trace showing what you are getting from that. Your `HandlerThread` replacement is wrong in a few spots. You could also consider more modern solutions, such as `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` or RxJava.

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm not sure how to highlight in code, but I added a comment right before the line that throws the exception.

Comment: @blackapps I thought that mTCPThread.connectToTCP() would run on the TCPThread because it is defined there.  Can you give me an example of where/how I should write the run()?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you let me know what I got wrong with the HandlerThread?  I'm hoping to stick to that, if I can debug it.  I didn't think I would need to use Executors because I'm only planning to use 2 threads (the main UI thread and the TCP thread).  I was under the impression Executors are used when you need many threads.

Comment: The run() is on the same place as in your first example using a thread.

Comment: Dont use a handler thread. If you need two threads then take two threads.

Comment: @blackapps It sounds like your suggestion is to use the original code.  Do you have any ideas on how I can resolve the NetworkOnMainThreadException when I run the original code in Android 7.1?  Why shouldn't I use a handler thread?  (I am somewhat new to Java and Android programming, so I don't fully understand the difference between thread and handlerThread.)

Comment: "I was under the impression Executors are used when you need many threads" -- `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` creates an `Executor` that uses a single thread. "Can you let me know what I got wrong with the HandlerThread?" -- calling a method on a `HandlerThread` does not cause that method to magically run on that `HandlerThread`. If you want code to run on that thread, create a `Handler()` tied to the `Looper` from the `HandlerThread`, then `post()` a `Runnable` to the `Handler`. Using a regular thread or an `Executor` would be simpler.